# Ruby. How to split a string element inside an array?

Tags: arrays, ruby, split

I have an array of arr=["abcd"]

Q1. Is there a simpler way to split the 'abcd' into arr=["a","b","c","d"] than the following:

```
    arr=["abcd"]
    arr_mod=[]
    x=0
    while x < arr[0].size
        arr_mod << arr[0][x]
        x +=1
    end
    puts "==>#{arr_mod}"
```

arr.split('') will not work.

Q2. Is there a method to convert arr=["abcd"] to the string of "abcd"?

Comment: Your code will not give `arr=["a","b","c","d"]`. Do you want to replace `arr` in place or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q1:

This would give you some flexibility in case you ever needed a way to iterate over an array of more than one element:

```
arr = ['abcd']
arr = arr[0].split("")
  #=> ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

Q2:

```
arr = ['abcd']
arr = arr[0]
  #=> "abcd"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
arr.first.split('')
  #=> ["a", "b", "c", "d"] 

arr.first
  #=> "abcd"
```

Comment: This is great.  I'd never have thought of this.  Thank you Cary!

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to do

`arr.join("").chars`

This turns the `arr` into one big string, then turns that string into an array of characters.

For your second question, just do `arr.join("")`, which will turn all the strings into the array into one big string.

For more information, check out [Array#join](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-join) and [String#chars](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-chars) for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Q1:

```
arr.map(&:chars).flatten
#=> ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

Q2:

```
arr = arr[0]
#=> "abcd"
```

Comment: Prefer `flat_map(&:chars)` to `map(&:chars).flatten`.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way:

```
arr.join.split('') #=> ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```